# PHPMailer : Everything works fine for 4 months, but suddenly SMTP connect() failed

Tags: php, phpmailer

I really have no idea what's wrong with PHPMailer, Mandrill or my hosting account. Everything works fine for last 4 months but today I got this error:

> Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.
>   https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

and here's what it looks like when `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;` enabled :

```
2016-08-16 15:30:08 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220-jkt03.dewaweb.com ESMTP Exim 4.87 #1
Tue, 16 Aug 2016 22:30:08 +0700 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail. 2016-08-16 15:30:08
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO komisian.com 2016-08-16 15:30:08 
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-jkt03.dewaweb.com Hello komisian.com [103.200.7.25] 250-SIZE 52428800 250-8BITMIME 250-PIPELINING 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN 250-STARTTLS 250 HELP 2016-08-16 15:30:08
CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS 2016-08-16 15:30:08
SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 TLS go ahead 2016-08-16 15:30:08
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO komisian.com 2016-08-16 15:30:08
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-jkt03.dewaweb.com Hello komisian.com [103.200.7.25] 250-SIZE 52428800 250-8BITMIME 250-PIPELINING 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN 250 HELP 2016-08-16 15:30:08
CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN 2016-08-16 15:30:12
SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6 2016-08-16 15:30:12
CLIENT -> SERVER: xxx 2016-08-16 15:30:12
SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6 2016-08-16 15:30:12
CLIENT -> SERVER: xxx== 2016-08-16 15:30:15
SERVER -> CLIENT: 535 Incorrect authentication data 2016-08-16 15:30:15
SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 535 Incorrect authentication data 2016-08-16 15:30:15  SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. 2016-08-16 15:30:15
CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT 2016-08-16 15:30:15
SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 jkt03.dewaweb.com closing connection 2016-08-16 15:30:15
SMTP connect() failed. 
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. 
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

Any idea what caused this error? Is this my hosting account's fault or Mandrill's? I have downloaded latest version of PHPMailer, but that's what I got as result.

FYI, I tested using this tutorial : https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582147-How-to-Send-with-PHPMailer

Thank you for your answer. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Q: How many emails "do" you send out on a regular basis? If you feel you're not sending too many out, then consider setting up an SPF record. This may reduce the chance of that.

Comment: Just to make sure: Do you have a paid SurveyMonkey account? [Mandrill became linked to paid SurveyMonkey accounts earlier this year](http://blog.mandrill.com/important-changes-to-mandrill.html). I don't know what their rollover process was like, but it's possible that your non-paid account was just deactivated…

Answer (score 2):

```
SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 535 Incorrect authentication data 2016-08-16 15:30:15  SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. 2016-08-16 15:30:15
```

Whatever it is, it is related to authentication data - double check username/password.

[The whole 53x group of SMTP errors](http://www.serversmtp.com/en/smtp-error) refers to username & password.

[RFC 4954](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4954) describes `535 Authentication credentials invalid`

> This response to the AUTH command indicates that the authentication
> failed due to invalid or insufficient authentication credentials.  In
> this case, the client SHOULD ask the user to supply new credentials
> (such as by presenting a password dialog box).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you set up your script to talk to mandrill (i.e you set `$mail->Host = 'smtp.mandrillapp.com';`, as per that example you linked to), but notice you've connected to `jkt03.dewaweb.com`, which is not a mandrill server (it looks like it's in Indonesia, as your domain is too), so I'd guess your ISP is transparently rerouting you to their own mail server, on which of course your mandrill credentials don't work.

It's likely that they changed their outbound email policy, causing this problem. It's quite common - GoDaddy does it and there are a zillion questions on here about that.

If you're running PHP prior to 5.6, or have disabled TLS certificate verification (as the PHPMailer docs describe), you can't detect this happening, which is why you shouldn't disable it! It means you've given away your mandrill credentials to your ISP - they are effectively doing a man-in-the-middle attack on you!

I've edited your SMTP output as it contained unprotected passwords.

Comment: Incidentally, that mandrill example is obsolete and will not work work with PHPMailer from the last year or so.

Answer (score 1):

It appears your hosting company may have changed their outgoing e-mail policy or tightened their spam filtering:

> ESMTP Exim 4.87 #1 Tue, 16 Aug 2016 22:30:08 +0700 220- We do not
>   authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or
>   bulk e-mail.

Otherwise, did you happen to change a password recently?

> SERVER -> CLIENT: 535 Incorrect authentication data 2016-08-16
>   15:30:15 
>   SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 535 Incorrect
>   authentication data
>   2016-08-16 15:30:15  SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. 2016-08-16 15:30:15

Comment: thanks for your answer, bro. I will contact my hosting company.

Comment: That's just a generic welcome banner, it doesn't mean anything, technically speaking.

Comment: @Synchro, fair enough, although that doesn't rule out the possibility, especially since we don't know if that message existed before.